# Not able to implement ctrl + click to open in new tab in FireFox with ng-Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    fromNgChange = true;
    var windowsEvent = $window;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        $(window).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey && fromNgChange) {
                windowsEvent.open('/html/apexEditor.html?name=' + newValue.name, '_blank');
                $scope.selectedName = possibleOldValues[0];
                fromNgChange = false;
                return;
            };
        })
    } else {
        // For chrome
        if (windowsEvent.event.ctrlKey) {
            windowsEvent.open('/html/apexEditor.html?name=' + newValue.name, '_blank');
            $scope.selectedName = possibleOldValues[0];
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

**Html code**

```
<select ng-model="selectedName"
        ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}')"
        ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
        class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

The issue here the code written for firefox ge
ts triggered as soon as I press ctrl button, and it misses the ng-change click.

This works fine in chrome but for firefox it does not work with the above code.
As soon as I do ctrl + click from the select tag, I think ctrl event gets fired and it misses ng-change click. Any workaround for this?

**Update**

```
if (windowsEvent.event.ctrlKey) { 
    windowsEvent.open('/html/apexEditor.html?name=' + newValue.name,'_blank'); 
    $scope.selectedName = possibleOldValues[0]; 
    return; 
}
```

This works but only in chrome, So I am trying to make it work in FireFox too.

**Update 2**

I have even tried passing the event like this: but it always shows null:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-keydown="$event = $event" ng-click="$event = $event" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', $event)"
            ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
            class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

**Update 2**

```
<div id="container" ng-click="event = $event">
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', {{event}})"
            ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
            class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This passes the event, but event only has type click and cannot determine if it was a ctrl + click, there is no event.ctrlKey in the event.

Comment: The handler is triggered by the `ctrl` key because you set it up as a "keydown" handler. That's what that kind of handler does: it fires when a **key** is pressed **down**.

Comment: Then how to change it to fire with click event ? Any idea?

Comment: Handle a "click" event and check for the `ctrl` key exactly like you do in Chrome.

Comment: but ng-click does not work same as ng-change.

Comment: Can you explain why are you registering the `keydown` again in case of `firefox`?

Comment: @FarooqKhan to detect ctrl key pressed so that when ng-change element is clicked with ctrl key pressed, I can open that in a new tab.

Comment: @NagendraSingh  the code in 1st `if` block seems redundant. You should be able to get `ctrl` press from `window` object.

Comment: @FarooqKhan no it is not possible to get ctrl from windows event in firefox, it only works in chrome.

Comment: @georgeawg updated the code above.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the IE horror [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) property, instead of using the correct reference to this event (the first argument of your handler). While this completely broken idea is unfortunately now part of the specs and Firefox implemented it in 63, you should really never use it.

Comment: @Kaiido I know this part. But the issue is that I cannot use ng-click as I need old and new values when change happens and also, when I ctrl+click on an element it should open in new tab. I know I should not use it. But what is the workaround or what else can I implement.